# Why aren't my animation keyframes triggering on hover?

Tags: css, animation, keyframe

**Description:**

I can't figure out why the items with the class `.specialItem`'s animation wont trigger. If you can figure out why, that would be great. The background / border changes no hover but it won't fade in like it should.

```js
$(window).on("resize", function() {
    var itemPercent = $("#percent");
    var itemCE = $("#ce");
    var itemC = $("#c");
    var itemDEL = $("#del");
    var itemDivide = $("#divide");
    var itemRoot = $("#squareRoot");
    var itemSeven = $("#seven");
    var itemEight = $("#eight");
    var itemNine = $("#nine");
    var itemMultiply = $("#multiply");
    var itemSupTwo = $("#supTwo");
    var itemFour = $("#four");
    var itemFive = $("#five");
    var itemSix = $("#six");
    var itemMinus = $("#minus");
    var itemSupThree = $("#supThree");
    var itemOne = $("#one");
    var itemTwo = $("#two");
    var itemThree = $("#three");
    var itemPlus = $("#plus");
    var itemUnSymbol = $("#unknownSymbol");
    var itemPosNeg = $("#posNeg");
    var itemZero = $("#zero");
    var itemDecimal = $("#decimal");
    var itemEquals = $("#equals");

    var defaultHeightCalc = $(window).height() - $(".output").height() - $(".special").height();
    $(".default").css("height", defaultHeightCalc);

    var itemHeightCalc = ($(".default").height() / 5 - 13);
    var itemWidthCalc = ($(".default").width() / 5 - 10);
    $(".item").css({
        "height": itemHeightCalc,
        "width": itemWidthCalc
    });
    $(".itemIconAlign").css("top", ($(".item").height() / 2) - ($(".itemIconAlign").height() / 2));
}).resize();
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans+Mono|Pacifico|Oxygen);
body {
    background: #EEEEEE;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.storage {
    height: 100%;
    width: 19%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
.main {
    height: 100%;
    width: 81%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
.output {
    height: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 104px;
    text-align: right;
}
.numLineAlign {
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.input {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.special {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
.default {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.storageNav {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.storageTab {
    height: 25%;
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    left: 0px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.item {
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-height: 50px;
}
.item:hover {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(80%);
    filter: brightness(80%);
}
#percent, #ce, #c, #del, #divide, #decimal, #minus, #plus, #equals,
#squareRoot, #supTwo, #supThree, #unknownSymbol, #posNeg, #multiply {
    background: #E0E0E0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#one, #two, #three, #four, #five,
#six, #seven, #eight, #nine, #zero {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.itemIconAlign {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
}
.specialItem {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px;
    margin-top: -23px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}
.specialItem:hover {
    background: #E0E0E0;
    border: 2px solid white;
    animation: fade 1s;
}
@keyframes fade {
    0% {
        background: #E0E0E0;
        border: 2px solid white;
    }
    100% {
        background: #E0E0E0;
        border: 2px solid white;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="storage">
        <div class="storageNav">
            <div class="storageTab">History</div>
            <div class="storageTab">Memory</div>
        </div>
        <div class="storageBox">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="output">
            <div class="numLineAlign">
                0
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <div class="special">
                <div class="specialItem" id="memClean">MC</div>
                <div class="specialItem" id="memRead">MR</div>
                <div class="specialItem" id="memAdd">M+</div>
                <div class="specialItem" id="memRemove">M-</div>
                <div class="specialItem" id="memStore">MS</div>
            </div>
            <div class="default">
                <div class="row" id="r1">
                    <div class="item" id="percent">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">%</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" id="ce">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">CE</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" id="c">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">C</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" id="del">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">DEL</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" id="divide">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">÷</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" id="r2">
                    <div class="item" id="squareRoot">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">√</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" id="seven">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">7</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" id="eight">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">8</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" id="nine">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">9</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" id="multiply">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">*</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" id="r3">
                    <div class="item" id="supTwo">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">x<sup>2</sup></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" id="four">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">4</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" id="five">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">5</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" id="six">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">6</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" id="minus">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">-</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" id="r4">
                    <div class="item" id="supThree">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">x<sup>3</sup></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" id="one">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">1</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" id="two">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">2</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" id="three">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">3</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" id="plus">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">+</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" id="r5">
                    <div class="item" id="unknownSymbol">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign"><sup>1</sup>/x</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" id="posNeg">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">±</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" id="zero">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">0</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" id="decimal">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">●</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" id="equals">
                        <div class="itemIconAlign">=</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have different values on 0% and 100% of your animation.

```
@keyframes fade {
    0% {background: #EEE; border: 2px solid #EEE;}
    100% {}
}
```

Also you can remove animation and use transition, in general when you would use only 0% and 100% you can use simple transition instead.

```
.specialItem {
    transition: all 1s;
}

.specialItem:hover {
    background: #E0E0E0;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
```

See snippet below.

```js
$(window).on("resize", function() {
    var itemPercent = $("#percent");     
    var itemCE = $("#ce");     
    var itemC = $("#c");     
    var itemDEL = $("#del");     
    var itemDivide = $("#divide");
    var itemRoot = $("#squareRoot");     
    var itemSeven = $("#seven");     
    var itemEight = $("#eight");     
    var itemNine = $("#nine");     
    var itemMultiply = $("#multiply");
    var itemSupTwo = $("#supTwo");     
    var itemFour = $("#four");     
    var itemFive = $("#five");     
    var itemSix = $("#six");     
    var itemMinus = $("#minus");
    var itemSupThree = $("#supThree");    
    var itemOne = $("#one");     
    var itemTwo = $("#two");     
    var itemThree = $("#three");     
    var itemPlus = $("#plus");
    var itemUnSymbol = $("#unknownSymbol");     
    var itemPosNeg = $("#posNeg");     
    var itemZero = $("#zero");     
    var itemDecimal = $("#decimal");     
    var itemEquals = $("#equals");
    
    var defaultHeightCalc = $(window).height() - $(".output").height() - $(".special").height();
    $(".default").css("height", defaultHeightCalc);
    
    var itemHeightCalc = ($(".default").height() / 5 - 13);
    var itemWidthCalc = ($(".default").width() / 5 - 10);
    $(".item").css({ "height" : itemHeightCalc, "width" : itemWidthCalc });
    $(".itemIconAlign").css("top", ($(".item").height() / 2) - ($(".itemIconAlign").height() / 2));
   }).resize();
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans+Mono|Pacifico|Oxygen);

body {
background: #EEEEEE;
overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.storage {
height: 100%;
width: 19%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
}

.main {
height: 100%;
width: 81%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}

.output {
height: 25%;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight: 900;
font-size: 104px;
text-align: right;
}

.numLineAlign {
position: relative;
top: 30%;
right: 0px;
width: 100%;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

.input {
width: 100%;
position: relative;
top: 0%;
left: 0px;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

.special {
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}

.default {
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
left: 0px;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

.storageNav {
height: 70px;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

.storageTab {
height: 25%;
position: relative;
top: 25%;
left: 0px;
color: black;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px;
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-weight: 600;
cursor: default;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

.item {
text-align: center;
background: white;
display: inline-block;
margin: 2px;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
cursor: pointer;
min-height: 50px;
}

.item:hover {
-webkit-filter: brightness(80%);
filter: brightness(80%);
}

#percent, #ce, #c, #del, #divide, #decimal, #minus, #plus, #equals, #squareRoot, #supTwo, #supThree, #unknownSymbol, #posNeg, #multiply {
background: #E0E0E0;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 20px;
}

#one, #two, #three, #four, #five, #six, #seven, #eight, #nine, #zero {
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-weight: 800;
font-size: 20px;
}

.itemIconAlign {
position: relative;
left: 0px;
}

.specialItem {
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-weight: 800;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: center;
padding: 25px;
margin-top: -23px;
cursor: pointer;
border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.specialItem {
    transition: all 1s;
}

.specialItem:hover {
    background: #E0E0E0;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="storage">
      <div class="storageNav">
       <div class="storageTab">History</div>
       <div class="storageTab">Memory</div>
      </div>
      <div class="storageBox">
      
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="main">
      <div class="output">
       <div class="numLineAlign">
        0
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input">
        <div class="special">
         <div class="specialItem" id="memClean">MC</div>
         <div class="specialItem" id="memRead">MR</div>
         <div class="specialItem" id="memAdd">M+</div>
         <div class="specialItem" id="memRemove">M-</div>
         <div class="specialItem" id="memStore">MS</div>
        </div>
        <div class="default">
         <div class="row" id="r1">
          <div class="item" id="percent">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">%</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="ce">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">CE</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="c">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">C</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="del">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">DEL</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="divide">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">÷</div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row" id="r2">
          <div class="item" id="squareRoot">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">√</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="seven">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">7</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="eight">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">8</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="nine">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">9</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="multiply">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">*</div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row" id="r3">
          <div class="item" id="supTwo">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">x<sup>2</sup></div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="four">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">4</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="five">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">5</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="six">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">6</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="minus">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">-</div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row" id="r4">
          <div class="item" id="supThree">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">x<sup>3</sup></div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="one">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">1</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="two">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">2</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="three">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">3</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="plus">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">+</div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row" id="r5">
          <div class="item" id="unknownSymbol">
           <div class="itemIconAlign"><sup>1</sup>/x</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="posNeg">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">±</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="zero">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">0</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="decimal">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">●</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="equals">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">=</div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working! (In Chrome at least)

The problem is that the animation doesn't change anything, rather the animation's `@keyframes` are the exact same as the values that are set in the `:hover`.

I changed the keyframe's value to display the difference.

```js
$(window).on("resize", function() {
    var itemPercent = $("#percent");     
    var itemCE = $("#ce");     
    var itemC = $("#c");     
    var itemDEL = $("#del");     
    var itemDivide = $("#divide");
    var itemRoot = $("#squareRoot");     
    var itemSeven = $("#seven");     
    var itemEight = $("#eight");     
    var itemNine = $("#nine");     
    var itemMultiply = $("#multiply");
    var itemSupTwo = $("#supTwo");     
    var itemFour = $("#four");     
    var itemFive = $("#five");     
    var itemSix = $("#six");     
    var itemMinus = $("#minus");
    var itemSupThree = $("#supThree");    
    var itemOne = $("#one");     
    var itemTwo = $("#two");     
    var itemThree = $("#three");     
    var itemPlus = $("#plus");
    var itemUnSymbol = $("#unknownSymbol");     
    var itemPosNeg = $("#posNeg");     
    var itemZero = $("#zero");     
    var itemDecimal = $("#decimal");     
    var itemEquals = $("#equals");
    
    var defaultHeightCalc = $(window).height() - $(".output").height() - $(".special").height();
    $(".default").css("height", defaultHeightCalc);
    
    var itemHeightCalc = ($(".default").height() / 5 - 13);
    var itemWidthCalc = ($(".default").width() / 5 - 10);
    $(".item").css({ "height" : itemHeightCalc, "width" : itemWidthCalc });
    $(".itemIconAlign").css("top", ($(".item").height() / 2) - ($(".itemIconAlign").height() / 2));
   }).resize();
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans+Mono|Pacifico|Oxygen);

body {
background: #EEEEEE;
overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.storage {
height: 100%;
width: 19%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
}

.main {
height: 100%;
width: 81%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}

.output {
height: 25%;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight: 900;
font-size: 104px;
text-align: right;
}

.numLineAlign {
position: relative;
top: 30%;
right: 0px;
width: 100%;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

.input {
width: 100%;
position: relative;
top: 0%;
left: 0px;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

.special {
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}

.default {
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
left: 0px;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

.storageNav {
height: 70px;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

.storageTab {
height: 25%;
position: relative;
top: 25%;
left: 0px;
color: black;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px;
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-weight: 600;
cursor: default;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

.item {
text-align: center;
background: white;
display: inline-block;
margin: 2px;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
cursor: pointer;
min-height: 50px;
}

.item:hover {
-webkit-filter: brightness(80%);
filter: brightness(80%);
}

#percent, #ce, #c, #del, #divide, #decimal, #minus, #plus, #equals, #squareRoot, #supTwo, #supThree, #unknownSymbol, #posNeg, #multiply {
background: #E0E0E0;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 20px;
}

#one, #two, #three, #four, #five, #six, #seven, #eight, #nine, #zero {
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-weight: 800;
font-size: 20px;
}

.itemIconAlign {
position: relative;
left: 0px;
}

.specialItem {
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-weight: 800;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: center;
padding: 25px;
margin-top: -23px;
cursor: pointer;
border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.specialItem:hover {
animation: fade 1s;
}

@keyframes fade {
0% {background: transparent; border: 2px solid transparent;}
100% {background: #E0E0E0; border: 2px solid white;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="storage">
      <div class="storageNav">
       <div class="storageTab">History</div>
       <div class="storageTab">Memory</div>
      </div>
      <div class="storageBox">
      
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="main">
      <div class="output">
       <div class="numLineAlign">
        0
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input">
        <div class="special">
         <div class="specialItem" id="memClean">MC</div>
         <div class="specialItem" id="memRead">MR</div>
         <div class="specialItem" id="memAdd">M+</div>
         <div class="specialItem" id="memRemove">M-</div>
         <div class="specialItem" id="memStore">MS</div>
        </div>
        <div class="default">
         <div class="row" id="r1">
          <div class="item" id="percent">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">%</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="ce">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">CE</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="c">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">C</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="del">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">DEL</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="divide">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">÷</div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row" id="r2">
          <div class="item" id="squareRoot">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">√</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="seven">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">7</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="eight">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">8</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="nine">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">9</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="multiply">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">*</div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row" id="r3">
          <div class="item" id="supTwo">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">x<sup>2</sup></div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="four">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">4</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="five">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">5</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="six">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">6</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="minus">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">-</div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row" id="r4">
          <div class="item" id="supThree">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">x<sup>3</sup></div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="one">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">1</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="two">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">2</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="three">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">3</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="plus">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">+</div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row" id="r5">
          <div class="item" id="unknownSymbol">
           <div class="itemIconAlign"><sup>1</sup>/x</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="posNeg">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">±</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="zero">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">0</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="decimal">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">●</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="item" id="equals">
           <div class="itemIconAlign">=</div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```